# Fetch latest tag of repo from URL

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Found this answer to help with gitPython and ssh keys [GitPython and SSH Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291909/gitpython-and-ssh-keys)

I want to dynamically use the latest tagged version for something, but without cloning the repo.. something like

```
import os
from git import Repo
from git import Git

git_ssh_identity_file = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
git_ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i %s' % git_ssh_identity_file

with Git().custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=git_ssh_cmd):
    repo = Git('git@<cdn>')
    # repo = Repo('git@<cdn>') # this doesn't work, gives a 'NoSuchPathError'

latest_tag = # how to get tags?
<do something with latest_tag>
```

I'm unable to find any examples and my git python knowledge is very small

Comment: "*`Repo('git@<cdn>')` doesn't work, gives a 'NoSuchPathError'*" You cannot open a remote repository, GitPython works only with local repos.

Comment: @phd welp that answers that. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21439488/7976758 Something like `git ls-remote --tags` See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+latest+tag+remote+repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35585837/7976758 `git ls-remote` in GitPython is `git.cmd.Git().ls_remote(url)` [gitpython] "ls-remote"